# VB6 application and a protected access database

Tags: ms-access, vb6

Can someone tell me how a Visual Basic 6.0 application can access a protected access database that I can't access using MS Access directly because I don't have the necessary permissions? The app can open the database without problems, but I can't open it with ms access. the app, the database and MS access are on the same computer. I use 6windows 10 with ms office 2010. The database i am trying to open was created with ms access 97

Comment: Can VB6 actually open and use a DB from Access 2010?

Comment: Is the database an .mdb file or an .accdb file? Can we also assume that "the app" is some kind of compiled application and you don't have the source code for it?

Comment: @Plutonix - A VB6 application should be able to open an .accdb database if it uses ADODB and either `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`.

Comment: I forgot to mention it's an MS Access 97 database

Comment: @GordThompson I don't have the source code. I am trying to migrate the data to an sql server 2014 database.

Comment: What do you mean by "permissions?"  File permissions or user/passwords?  Keep in mind that Jet databases support two levels of password security.

Comment: @Bob77 I get the following message "You do not have the necessary permissions to use accessDB.MDB object" when I try to open the Database with MS Access.

Comment: Ahh, didn't associate it with the proper Workgroup database?  Maybe see http://chrisstark.co/2013/01/microsoft-access-error-you-do-not-have-the-necessary-permissions-to-use-the/